# Cast Video and Video Ads to TV from Android phone

Tags: android, google-cast, exoplayer, imasdk

I am trying to cast Video and Video Ads to TV from Android phone, i tried to run the official example but it not working, can anyone point out a good tutorial which i can follow. I am already using exoplayer and ima sdk v3 to play videos and ads.

Comment: Can you provide your error logs?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without a receiver you can verify this samples https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-cast or the official docs https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/cast/client-side/receiver